# Can't retrieve profile information for a signed in user (Android)

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm trying to retrieve profile information for a signed in user, but problem is that

```
Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(googleApiClient)
```

always returns null.

Here is my google api client:

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity()).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(googleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {}
    });
    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(googleApiClient) != null) {

        .....
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this call returning `null` was that the Google+ API Was not enabled for your application. Navigate to https://console.developers.google.com, select your project and enable the Google+ API to get it working!

Like this :

[image]

and

[image]

Check this for more detail [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/)

Comment: Thanks for answer but I already did this.
Google+ api have been enabled at beginning of project and I also added client ID for android application.
In log cat I found this two errors:
11-26 04:45:15.098: E/Volley(1383): [64] a.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
11-26 04:45:15.308: E/Volley(1383): [65] a.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?maxResults=100&orderBy=alphabetical

Comment: I did this. For using app user must login with Google+ and this works fine. But now I can't retrieve data.

Comment: `@Override
 public void onConnected() {
   ...
   if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
  Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
  String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
  String personPhoto = currentPerson.getImage();
  String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
   }
 }`
 
 debug and tell the json response of it 
 
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People.html#getCurrentPerson(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)

Comment: I made new client id with my private key. In onConnected
method I added 

 String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(googleApiClient);
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnected 343,  " + accountName);
and  I get correct accountName.

But Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(googleApiClient) is still null.